# How to configure Shiro with Shiro.ini when using Spring's Java Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, security, shiro, spring-java-config

I am using Apache Shiro with Spring and using Spring's Java config only. (no xml).
Below is a portion of my config class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter(DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager) {
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean factoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

    String shiroIniContents = readFile(new ClassPathResource("shiro.ini").getFile().toPath());
    factoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitions(shiroIniContents);//only reads the [urls] section

    factoryBean.setLoginUrl("/rest/login");

    return factoryBean;
}


@Bean
public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager()  {
    DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    securityManager.setRealm(stormpathRealm());
    return securityManager;
}
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to load `shiro.ini` by passing it to `ShiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitions()`.

But that method only loads the contents of the `[urls]` section. So anything in the `[main]` section is left untouched.

So then, how/where do I configure shiro using the full contents of shiro.ini?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448460/spring-mvc-and-shiro-configuration-using-ini-files). You should try to refactor everything to Java config instead of using `.ini` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try what the [documentation](http://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html) says and create a `SecurityManager` from the `ini` file

```
Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
```

and in your `@Bean` method

```
ShiroFilterFactoryBean factoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
factoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager); // referring to previous
```

You will need to cast the `securityManager` to `DefaultSecurityManager` if you need to further configure it.

You really should not use `shiro.ini` when using Spring. You have much stronger tools at your disposal.